# How to remove the space on left side of the editor in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022. I want to conserve the space on the left in the editor shown in this screen shot:
[image]
More generic question is how to customise the chrome of Visual Studio Community edition. I'm ok with editing the source code of Visual Studio if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Select `Tools>Options>Text Editor>General` and uncheck `Selection Margin` and `Indicator Margin`. You will still be able to insert breakpoints by right clicking a line of code and selecting `Breakpoint>Insert breakpoint`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. The significant gap between the border of the text editor and the line number column is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Settings>Text Editor>Glyph Margin , uncheck it and some of the gap will be gone atleast it erased some gap for me

Same gap called "gut space" in some other IDEs by the way in case you hit the same problem somewhere else